# No llega correo enviado desde jquery y phpmailer

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

soy nuevo aquí, he estado buscando información en todos los posts anteriores, en google y no doy con la solución.
Les comento, estoy trabajando con PHPMailer, tengo el fichero sendemail.php el cual recibe la información mediante ajax, el problema es que, al recibir la información desde ajax me sale el mensaje de que SI se ha enviado el correo, pero no llega a ningún lado, ni a la bandeja de entrada ni a SPAM, tanto a GMAIL como a YAHOO. Pero si en vez de recibir los datos por ajax, se los agrego manualmente en el mismo fichero sendemail.php, ahí SI llega tanto a GMAIL como a YAHOO.

Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza desde hace 1 día y medio y no doy con el problema, he utilizado desde la versión 1 hasta la 6 de PHPMailer y lo mismo, he utilizado los mensajes de debug para ver las diferencias entre lo que envía recibiendo los datos desde ajax y poniéndolos manualmente y no hay diferencias, pero en un caso NO llega el correo y en el otro SI.

Y desde el fichero ajax ya he revisado que la información esté llegando al SENDEMAIL.PHP y si que llega sin problemas, pero no llega el correo a GMAIL ni a YAHOO

Si tienen alguna idea, me lo hacen saber, gracias de antemano.

Les paso el código de los ficheros y los mensajes entregados, ya no se que más revisar, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos

Jonathan Juarez

SENDEMAIL.PHP

```
// Mostrar errores PHP (Desactivar en producción)
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Incluir la libreria PHPMailer
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

    //Información del email
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];


    /*$nombre = "Johan Vasquez";
    $email = "correo@correo.com";
    $asunto = "consulta";
    $mensaje = "Hola, queria saber más";*/


    //Definimos primero la zona horaria
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    //Las variable para obtener la fecha y hora
    $hora = date('H:i');
    $nombreDia = date('w');
    $fechaDia = date('d');
    $nombreMes = date('n');
    $año = date('Y');

    //Array de los días de la semana
    $diasemana = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");

    //Array de los meses del año
    $meses = array("Enero","febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

  
    //Envío del email
    //Ahora lo que hacemos es instanciar un objeto de la clase.
    //$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    

     //Envío del email
    //Ahora lo que hacemos es instanciar un objeto de la clase.
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setLanguage("es"); 
    //A ese objeto le indicamos que vamos a utilizar el envío mediante SMTP.
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    
    //Y que vamos a utilizar el envío autentificado.
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    
    //Por último le indicamos que en el cuerpo del mensaje, enviaremos información con formato HTML.
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    
    //A continuación le indicaremos los datos que tiene que utilizar para hacer el envío del correo mediante el protocolo SMTP Autentificado.
    $mail->Host = nombredelservidor;
    $mail->Username = "usuario";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    
    //Hecho este paso, indicamos el nombre de quien hace el envío y la dirección de mail que lo envía.
    //Hay que tener cuidado de no confundir con el nombre y la dirección de mail del destinatario.
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = utf8_decode($nombre);
    
    //A continuación indicamos el o los correos a los que se le envía el mail. 
    //En nuestro caso sólo pondremos uno, pero se puede añadir tanto como queramos.
    $mail->addAddress("jonathan.iesgalileo@gmail.com");
    
    //Indicamos el asunto que llevará el mail.
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($asunto);
        
        $cuerpo_mensaje = 'Este correo es enviado desde tu tarjeta de visita:
            <br>
            El <strong>'. $diasemana[$nombreDia] .' '. $fechaDia .' de '. $meses[$nombreMes-1] .' del '. $año .'</strong>
            <br>A las <strong>'.$hora.'</strong><br><br>
            Nombre: <strong>'.$nombre.'</strong><br>
            Correo: <strong>'.$email.'</strong><br>
            Mensaje:<br>'. $mensaje .'<br><br><br><br>';
        
            
        //El cuerpo del mensaje, que en nuestro caso contendrá código HTML.
        $mail->Body = utf8_decode($cuerpo_mensaje);
        
        //Para terminar, le añadimos el texto que queremos que vean aquellos usuarios cuyos clientes de mail no muestran HTML. 
        //Se trata de un campo optativo pero muy recomendable de utilizar.
        $mail->AltBody = $mensaje;
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        
        //Hechos todos estos pasos, sólo faltaría enviar el correo.
        $mail->send();

        if($mail->ErrorInfo == "") 
        { 
            echo $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;; 
        }
        else
        {   
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo; 
        }
```

Esto es lo que devuelve el debug al hacer el envío, solo pongo 1 porque el otro es igual, la única diferencia es la hora y el encriptado del mensaje

MENSAJE DEL DEBUG

```
    2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-webhosting2001.is.cc ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Sun, 01 Nov 2020 08:15:38 -0500 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO motarvi.com
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-webhosting2001.is.cc Hello motarvi.com [209.159.149.194]250-SIZE 104857600250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO motarvi.com
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-webhosting2001.is.cc Hello motarvi.com [209.159.149.194]250-SIZE 104857600250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<coreo@coreo.com>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<jonathan.iesgalileo@gmail.com>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2020-11-01 13:15:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sun, 1 Nov 2020 14:15:38 +0100
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: jonathan.iesgalileo@gmail.com
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Juan Perez <coreo@coreo.com>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Consulta
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <uqJOM29wH5XLR171xQgsVyDd85u8dty7Lqgr1vlbIg@motarvi.com>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.8 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_uqJOM29wH5XLR171xQgsVyDd85u8dty7Lqgr1vlbIg"
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_uqJOM29wH5XLR171xQgsVyDd85u8dty7Lqgr1vlbIg
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Hola, quería saber más
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_uqJOM29wH5XLR171xQgsVyDd85u8dty7Lqgr1vlbIg
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Este correo es enviado desde tu tarjeta de visita:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: <br>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: El <strong>Domingo 01 de Noviembre del 2020</strong>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: <br>A las <strong>14:15</strong><br><br>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Nombre: <strong>Juan Perez</strong><br>
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: Correo: <strong>coreo@coreo.com</strong><br>
2020-11-01 13:15:38
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_uqJOM29wH5XLR171xQgsVyDd85u8dty7Lqgr1vlbIg--
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-11-01 13:15:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2020-11-01 13:15:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1kZDCs-000ah0-RF
2020-11-01 13:15:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-11-01 13:15:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 webhosting2001.is.cc closing connection
2
```

Comment: Prueba a comentar esta línea: `$mail->isSMTP();` y dinos si funciona.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADOOOO, por fin.

En esta parte

```
$mail->From = $email;
```

Estaba poniendo el correo que escribía el usuario, lo he modificado con un correo existente mio del estilo: no-reply@midominio.com y ahora funciona perfectamente, gracias A.Cedano, saludos